# Avoid for loops by apply - worth the trouble?

Tags: r

I wrote a Rscript to bring some data in a desired format. In particular I just want to rearrange the dataset to finally have it in a format of 8 rows and 12 columns (96-well plate format). I nested two for loops which works perfectly fine:

```
element1 = seq(1,96,1)
element2 = seq(0.5,48,0.5)
df = data.frame(element1,element2)
storage = data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 8, ncol = 12))
container = vector("list",ncol(df))

for (n in 1:ncol(df)){
      j = 0  
        for (i in seq(1,length(df[,n]),12)) { 
              j = j+1
              storage[j,] = df[(i):(i+11),n]  
          }
     container[[n]]=storage

}
```

Remark:
I packed the data in a list for easier exporting in .xls
And I know that this is a really unsophisticated approach...but it works

I am however willing to learn :-) as I read lot one should avoid for loops and use "apply" in combination with functions instead. I tried to solve the task by using apply and functions. However I was not able to get the result and the usage of functions and apply seemed much more complex to me. So is it always worth to avoid for loops? If yes, how would you do it?

Thanks, Christian

Comment: What is the purpose of this line --> `container[[n]]=table`?

Comment: I used it in order to have all rearranged "storage"s in one list to export them to excel.

Comment: @nrussell I think it's supposed to be `container[[n]]= storage`

Comment: Pure R code is surprisingly slow. Anything you can `lapply` or delegate to native code (matrix multiplications etc.) does really pay off.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse `lapply` is equivalent to a `for` loop. The reason MrFlicks answer is an improvement is because he doesn't nest two loops and because he isn't creating new objects and then updating them in each nested/higher loop.

Comment: Thank all of you! I am quite new to R and comments like yours really help! I can see the point that the usage of lapply is much more convinient here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appears to just be reshaping each column to a matrix. How about just

```
container <- lapply(df, matrix, byrow=T, ncol=12)
```

if you really need a data.frame, try

```
container <- lapply(df, function(x) data.frame(matrix(x, byrow=T, ncol=12)))
```